# Spring boot mongo audit @version issue

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I just started a new project and would like to use Sprint Boot 2.1 and ran into a problem at the very beginning. What I would like to do is use Spring Boot Mongo to manage the database. I would like to have an optimistic lock with `@Version` annotation. However, I found that it seems like `@Version` would affect the `save()` behavior in MongoRepository, which means, dup key error.

The following is the sample code. 
**POJO**

```
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Document
    public class Person {

        @Id public ObjectId id;
        @CreatedDate public LocalDateTime createOn;
        @LastModifiedDate public LocalDateTime modifiedOn;
        @Version public long version;
        private String name;
        private String email;

        public Person(String name, String email) {
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
        }

       @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Person [id=%s, name=%s, email=%s, createdOn=%s, modifiedOn=%s, version=%s]", id, name, email, createOn, modifiedOn, version);
        }
    }
```

**MongoConfig**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableMongoRepositories("com.project.server.repo")
    @EnableMongoAuditing
    public class MongoConfig {

    }
```

**Repository**

```
    public interface PersonRepo extends MongoRepository<Person, ObjectId> {
        Person save(Person person);
        Person findByName(String name);
        Person findByEmail(String email);
        long count();
        @Override
        void delete(Person person);
    }
```

As indicated in [Official Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#version), I have my `version` field in `long`, but the dup key error occurs at the second `save`, which means it tried to `insert` again, even with the id in the object. 
I also tried with `Long` in `version` field, which has no dup key occurred and save as update as expected, but the `createdOn` become `null` in the first `save` (which means `insert`)

**Controller**

```
Person joe = new Person("Joe", "aa@aa.aa");
System.out.println(joe.toString());
this.personRepo.save(joe);
Person who = this.personRepo.findByName("Joe");
System.out.println(who.toString());
who.setEmail("bb@bb.bb");
this.personRepo.save(who);
Person who1 = this.personRepo.findByName("Joe");
Person who2 = this.personRepo.findByEmail("bb@bb.bb");
System.out.println(who1.toString());
System.out.println(who2.toString());
```

**log with dup key** (`long version`)

```
    2018-11-11 02:09:31.435  INFO 4319 --- [on(6)-127.0.0.1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:186}] to localhost:27017
    Person [id=null, name=Joe, email=aa@aa.aa, createdOn=null, modifiedOn=null, version=0]
    2018-11-11 02:09:37.254 DEBUG 4319 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.data.auditing.AuditingHandler        : Touched Person [id=null, name=Joe, email=aa@aa.aa, createdOn=2018-11-11T02:09:37.252, modifiedOn=2018-11-11T02:09:37.252, version=0] - Last modification at 2018-11-11T02:09:37.252 by unknown
    2018-11-11 02:09:37.259 DEBUG 4319 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : Inserting Document containing fields: [createOn, modifiedOn, version, name, email, _class] in collection: person
    2018-11-11 02:09:37.297 DEBUG 4319 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.d.m.r.query.MongoQueryCreator        : Created query Query: { "name" : "Joe" }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }
    2018-11-11 02:09:37.304 DEBUG 4319 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { "name" : "Joe" } fields: Document{{}} for class: class com.seedu.server.model.Person in collection: person
    Person [id=5be71ee11ad34410df06852c, name=Joe, email=aa@aa.aa, createdOn=2018-11-11T02:09:37.252, modifiedOn=2018-11-11T02:09:37.252, version=0]
    2018-11-11 02:09:37.323 DEBUG 4319 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.data.auditing.AuditingHandler        : Touched Person [id=5be71ee11ad34410df06852c, name=Joe, email=bb@bb.bb, createdOn=2018-11-11T02:09:37.323, modifiedOn=2018-11-11T02:09:37.323, version=0] - Last modification at 2018-11-11T02:09:37.323 by unknown
    2018-11-11 02:09:37.324 DEBUG 4319 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : Inserting Document containing fields: [_id, createOn, modifiedOn, version, name, email, _class] in collection: person
    org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: seedu.person index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5be71ee11ad34410df06852c') }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: seedu.person index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5be71ee11ad34410df06852c') }
```

**log with createdDate null** (`Long version`)

```
    2018-11-11 02:07:28.858  INFO 4310 --- [on(6)-127.0.0.1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:183}] to localhost:27017
    Person [id=null, name=Joe, email=aa@aa.aa, createdOn=null, modifiedOn=null, version=null]
    2018-11-11 02:07:31.519 DEBUG 4310 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.data.auditing.AuditingHandler        : Touched Person [id=null, name=Joe, email=aa@aa.aa, createdOn=null, modifiedOn=2018-11-11T02:07:31.518, version=0] - Last modification at 2018-11-11T02:07:31.518 by unknown
    2018-11-11 02:07:31.525 DEBUG 4310 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : Inserting Document containing fields: [modifiedOn, version, name, email, _class] in collection: person
    2018-11-11 02:07:31.564 DEBUG 4310 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.d.m.r.query.MongoQueryCreator        : Created query Query: { "name" : "Joe" }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }
    2018-11-11 02:07:31.571 DEBUG 4310 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { "name" : "Joe" } fields: Document{{}} for class: class com.seedu.server.model.Person in collection: person
    Person [id=5be71e631ad34410d6a3b123, name=Joe, email=aa@aa.aa, createdOn=null, modifiedOn=2018-11-11T02:07:31.518, version=0]
    2018-11-11 02:07:31.590 DEBUG 4310 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.data.auditing.AuditingHandler        : Touched Person [id=5be71e631ad34410d6a3b123, name=Joe, email=bb@bb.bb, createdOn=null, modifiedOn=2018-11-11T02:07:31.590, version=1] - Last modification at 2018-11-11T02:07:31.590 by unknown
    2018-11-11 02:07:31.598 DEBUG 4310 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : Calling update using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5be71e631ad34410d6a3b123" }, "version" : { "$numberLong" : "0" } } and update: { "modifiedOn" : { "$date" : 1541873251590 }, "version" : { "$numberLong" : "1" }, "name" : "Joe", "email" : "bb@bb.bb", "_class" : "com.seedu.server.model.Person" } in collection: person
    2018-11-11 02:07:31.602 DEBUG 4310 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.d.m.r.query.MongoQueryCreator        : Created query Query: { "name" : "Joe" }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }
    2018-11-11 02:07:31.602 DEBUG 4310 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { "name" : "Joe" } fields: Document{{}} for class: class com.seedu.server.model.Person in collection: person
    2018-11-11 02:07:31.603 DEBUG 4310 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.d.m.r.query.MongoQueryCreator        : Created query Query: { "email" : "bb@bb.bb" }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }
    2018-11-11 02:07:31.604 DEBUG 4310 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { "email" : "bb@bb.bb" } fields: Document{{}} for class: class com.seedu.server.model.Person in collection: person
    Person [id=5be71e631ad34410d6a3b123, name=Joe, email=bb@bb.bb, createdOn=null, modifiedOn=2018-11-11T02:07:31.590, version=1]
    Person [id=5be71e631ad34410d6a3b123, name=Joe, email=bb@bb.bb, createdOn=null, modifiedOn=2018-11-11T02:07:31.590, version=1]
```

As I know, the spring use id existence as the save behavior control, which means if the id exists then save would be like the insert for mongo. However, in here, version seems also affect the save behavior or affect the way that spring recognize the id existence.

Question: How can I use MongoAudit with MongoRepository together? Is there any mistake/bug I made?

Comment: And, without `@Version`, everything works fine. 
My Spring-Boot version is 2.1.0.RELEASE and Java version is 1.8

Comment: I was going to ask a similar question! We are upgrading from Spring Boot 1.5.x to Spring Boot 2.1.0, and the behaviour changed. Same code that was working before (version is Long) now does not set the createdDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still can't figure out the problem. However, even though I have the exactly the same setting as the post above, since I upgrade Spring Boot from 2.1.0 to 2.1.1, everything works fine now(no matter what type of version I am using, Long/long)

Following is the library version I'm using right now.

```
spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.1.1.RELEASE:
  -> spring-data-mongo:2.1.3.RELEASE
  -> mongodb-driver:3.8.2
```

Answer (score 3):

For working with `@Version`, You have to retrieve the data model first from the database and after updating the data, you have to save the same data to the database.
For example:

```
  personRepo.findByName(name).ifPresent(person-> {
            person.setEmail("email@gamil.com");
            personRepo.save(person);
            log.info("Updated Data: {}", person);
        });
```

`@CreatedDate` will always be `null` if you didn't add the `@Version` to your model class. It works with `@Version`

One more point to add here if you didn't add `@Version` to your model class and you're trying to update the same with having model class `@Version`, it will again give you duplicate id error.